# Scaling a gene expression data generates NA values

Tags: r, logistic, high-dimensional, feature-scaling, train-test-split

I would like to analyze the prostate gene expression data which has a link named **12859_2005_967_MOESM4_ESM.tgz** in the site [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-7-228).

In a paper I read, the author scaled the predictors in the training set before fitting a logistic regression model. Hence, I need to scale the predictors in the training set to unit variance before the analysis.

However, my program code (in `R`) generated NA values after scaling the data.

What can be the reason for this?

The code is below:

```
library(R.matlab)
library(dplyr)

data <- readMat("prostate_data_label.mat")

X <- data$prostate.data
colnames(X) <- paste0("Gene",1:ncol(X))
y <- data$prostate.label
y <- y-1
colnames(y) <- "y"

datab <- cbind(y,X)
datab <- as.data.frame(datab)

ind1 <- which(y==1)
ind0 <- which(y==0)

set.seed(1)
train.ind1 <- sample(ind1, size=floor(length(ind1)*0.7))
train.ind0 <- sample(ind0, size=floor(length(ind0)*0.7))
train.ind <- c(train.ind1, train.ind0)

train <- datab %>% slice(train.ind)
test <- datab %>% slice(-train.ind)

trainx <- train %>% select(-"y")
trainy <- train %>% select("y")

trainx <- scale(trainx)

any(is.na(trainx))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice point made by @Misius. You may find the the degenerate random variables with the following: which(sapply(trainx, var) == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have problems with the genes that do not show any variation.  For example, I had a look at `Gene783` where you get NA values after the scaling: the column corresponding to this gene in your data consists only of ones. It is impossible to scale the degenerate random variable in a way that will result in it having a unit variance.

I do not have much experience with the `scale` function myself, but I guess it tries to do that, fails, but the result is NA.

You have quite a few of such predictors, you can find their names by `which(is.na(colSums(trainx)))`.

I would remove them from the sample before performing logistic regression.

Comment: I'm aware that is the result of small/no variation. However, this data set was used in many papers, and they reported the results. If the data can not be scaled, how did they obtain them?

Comment: @mert I think that you are talking about some other paper, because in the one you are citing the authors do not mention neither scaling, nor logistic regression. Unfrotunately, I can not comment on how people obtained some results without knowing the context.

Comment: There is also a possibility that their training set included some variation of the data so they could scale the results. For example, talking about Gene783, there is one entry that is not equal to 1.0, and if this entry is in the training set, then the data can be scaled.

Comment: I think that is not the case. Because they claim that they used random splitting and repeated the process 50 times. This is one of the papers: Penalized logistic regression with the adaptive LASSO for gene selection in high-dimensional cancer classification. Anyway, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see that they assume the genes are standardized but they never actually say how they standardize them in practice. If I would be trying to replicate their study, I think I would just leave those genes as they are, maybe only scaling them so that they lie in [-1, 1]. With couple of genes, it does not matter that much. I guess they wouldn't be selected anyway.

Comment: Actually, they mention the standardization type on page 9328, above equation 5. They mentioned a unit variance standardization. I assumed they applied this standardization to their data sets because they mentioned it there. Also, I tried scaling to [-1,1] and had still NA's.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but it is mentioned in the theory context, not with respect to the real data. You got NAs probably because you divided by (max-min), but if the data consists only of one value, then I would just divide it by this value. What I basically mean: I would not rely on a built-in function for these special cases.